# Enabling Intel VT on Macbook Pro 9,2 (Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, virtualization, android

I want to enable (if it's not) Intel VT-x to speed up the Android emulator.

How can I see if it's enabled and if not how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple says](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2744) VT-x technology is enabled on Intel-based Macs.

It seems to be (after this page) that only first Intel-based Macs may have some problem with VT-x so it should not be your case.